# Mongo: aggregate $geoNear and $text no results

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm trying to do a geoNear + text search aggregate query in Mongoose:

```
landmarkSchema.aggregate(
   [
      { "$geoNear": {
        "near": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [parseFloat(userCoord1), parseFloat(userCoord0)]
        },
        "distanceField": "distance",
        "minDistance": 1,
        "maxDistance": 5000,
        "spherical": true,
        "query": { "loc.type": "Point" }
      } },
      { $match: { $text: { $search: sText } } },
      { $sort: { score: { $meta: "textScore" } } }

  ],
  function(err,data) {
    if (data){
      res.send(data);
    }
    else {
        console.log('no results');
        res.send({err:'no results'});            
    }
});
```

But Mongo is not returning any results. When I perform each query separately, `$geoNear` and `$match : $text` the correct results are returned. Am I chaining the query incorrectly?

Comment: From mongodb IRC a user said: "only one index can be used for an aggregation" – anyone have a best practice for this type of query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only an initial `$match` stage can use an index, so you cannot use a text index in the second `$match`. You also can't combine using a 2dsphere index and using a text index in the same `$match`. One option is switching the order of the text search `$match` stage and the `$geoNear` stage. Swapped, the text search will use a text index and `$geoNear` will still work if you set `spherical : false`. `$geoNear` will calculate planar, not spherical, distances, and will not use an index.

If that's not feasible, we could try to think of other options if you describe the use case.

Comment: This answer didn't work for me and it seems it is outdated. $geoNear can ONLY be at the first stage of an aggregation. Source: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/#behavior

Answer (score 6):

Alternatively to @wdberkeley's answer, you can use `$geoWithin` instead of the `$geoNear` stage.

```
db.landmarkSchema.aggregate([
  {$match: {
      $text: {$search: "great test text"} ,
      loc: {$geoWithin: {$centerSphere: [[ 14.3, 48.3], 5/6731]}}
  }}])
```

Note: The geo index won't be used!

More information: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/geoWithin/