# Mongodb: Error: Arguments must be aggregate pipeline operators

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have been looking at this piece of code for a while now and cannot for the life of me find the error. Any help is much appreciated. Here is the code:

```
Item.aggregate(
  [
    { "$match": { "$text": { "$search": query} } },
    { "$geoNear": {
        "near": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [parseFloat(lon),parseFloat(lat)]
        },
        "distanceField": "distance",
        "spherical": true,
        "maxDistance": 33000
    }},
    {"score":{"$meta": "textScore"}},
    { "$sort": { "distance": 1, "score": { "$meta": "textScore" } } },
    {"$limit": 20}
], callback);
```

Comment: Try removing the `{"score":{"$meta": "textScore"}},` element from your pipeline array.

Comment: @JohnnyHK thanks for that. Now I have a new error. Both geoNear and match throw an error saying that they both have to be the first in the pipeline stage... Is there any way to deal with this? I have looked at other stackoverflow answers but they did not give much of a solution for this either http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28684188/mongo-aggregate-geonear-and-text-no-results