# How to use $geoNear with $match in aggregate mongoose nodejs

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregate

With code like that I can get near a location with a radius :
[image]

And I want to search by text after getting near a location like this:

[image]

But I still not working :(
How can I use both of geoNear and match text in aggregate?

Comment: Possible dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28684188/mongo-aggregate-geonear-and-text-no-results

Comment: But with geoWithin in your link . I can get distance from center to location like geoNear :(

Comment: Thanks for reply :D But Use $match stage before the $geoNear have error like $geoNear must be first of pipeline :v